# Why isn't this equation looping how I expect?

Tags: c, arguments, pass-by-value

I'm trying to calculate a price decrease based on percentages. If I write it out by hand, it comes out like the equation below, a simple x = x - (10% of x) , or new_price = old_price - (10% of old_price). So 100 would become 90, 90 would become 81, and so on. I think. I'm not sure if I'm brainfarting or what, but when I run this, it just forever loops "90" as output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int pricedecrease(int x)
{
    x = x - (x / 10.0);
    return  x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int price = 100;

    while(price > 3)
    {
        printf("%d\n", pricedecrease(price));
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass by value, that's why.

Comment: You're not modifying `price` between calls to printf.

Comment: Nice answers but I like this: 

printf("%d\n", price = pricedecrease(price));

Comment: You like it because it's shorter, or because it's less manageable?

Comment: Because in this occasion there is no need for pointers and many lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your price variable in the loop.  Calling the `pricedecrease` function will not modify the `price` variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int pricedecrease(int x)
{
    x = x - (x / 10.0);
    return  x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int price = 100;

    while(price > 3)
    {
        printf("%d\n", price);
        price = pricedecrease(price); // <- need to update price variable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function parameters are passed by value in C, and so the function body does not affect the value of the parameter when the function returns to the caller.

In your case, you return the adjusted value as a return value, so you can assign the return value to your variable.

```
while (price > 3)
{
    price = pricedecrease(price);
    printf("%d\n", price);
}
```

Comment: You are very welcome. You might consider accepting some of the answers to your questions. You receive a couple rep each time you do.

Answer (score 1):

It's an infinite loop because `price` is not modified.

Function parameters are passed as a copy onto the stack. In order to modify the original, you'll need to use pointers and pass the address of `price`.

```
int pricedecrease(int *x)
{
    *x -= (*x / 10.0);

    return *x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int price = 100;

    while(price > 3)
    {
        printf("%d\n", pricedecrease(&price));
    }
}
```